# Load data into multiple excel sheets depending on conditions dynamically

Tags: excel, ssis, ssms, ssms-2016, ssis-2017

I have a situation please help me out. I have to create multiple sheet in one excel file with different queries. Like i have to check if the particular column is null then the record against this query should be in excel file in new sheet and i have to check another column with other name if it is null or empty and then create a sheet for it and sheet should be created only if the query returns some result otherwise there should not be any empty sheet.  i have 8 different columns to check .

For Example I have to execute following query which will be in source

```
SELECT DISTINCT AgencySourceSystemCode,SourceAgencyID,ProgramCode,PolicyNumber,EffectiveDate,AgencyName 
FROM POL.vw_PolicyPremiumData 
WHERE AgencyName IS NULL OR AgencyName = ''
```

And Sample result is

```
AgencySourceSystemCode SourceAgencyID
ProgramCode PolicyNumber
EffectiveDate AgencyName
GEN 1050-  CAB DN17000008
2010-06-10 NULL
GEN 1050-  CAB DN17000008
2011-06-10 NULL
GEN 1050-  CAB DN17000008
2012-06-10 NULL
GEN 1050-  CAB DN17000010
2010-06-10 NULL
GEN 1050-  CAB DN17000010
2012-06-10 NULL
GEN 1050-  CAB DN17000012
2010-06-22 NULL
GEN 1050-  CAB DN17000012
2011-06-22 NULL
```

Here Agency Name is NULL like this i will have source query where Effective can be null  .

Comment: Ok, so what's you're question? What does SSMS have to do with this?

Comment: I think the easiest way to do this is to have 8 data flows with the correct SQL to it own destination.

Comment: However, you can have all your data with one query and conditionally split out 8 different paths.  BUT, if an item meets 2 or more conditions then it will only go down the 1st successful path. I don't know your data well enough to answer this.

Comment: @KeithL Hi,

Thanks for the help i have done it using script task. Please see attached code snippet .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this code snippet to create dynamic Excel file sheets .

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace ST_db9b6187d17c4dc99314d6ccb6ee7b08
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {
        string query = string.Empty;
        string FileName = string.Empty;
        string TableName = string.Empty;
        string connstring = string.Empty;
        string FolderPath = string.Empty;
        string where = string.Empty;
        string PackageName = "Error";
        int SourceId = 0;
        int BatchId = 0;
        int flag = 0;

        public void Main()
        {
            string datetime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");

            try
            {
                FolderPath = Dts.Variables["$Package::TempFolderPath"].Value.ToString();
                FolderPath = FolderPath+"\\";
                //if (FolderPath.LastIndexOf("\\")="\\")
                //{
                //    FolderPath = Dts.Variables["$Package::TempFolderPath"].Value.ToString();
                //}
                if (File.Exists(FolderPath + PackageName + "File.XLSX"))
                {
                    File.Delete(FolderPath + PackageName + "File.XLSX");
                }

                if (FolderPath.Contains(".xlsx"))
                {
                    FolderPath = FolderPath.Trim('\\');
                    FolderPath = FolderPath.Remove(FolderPath.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
                }

                //USE ADO.NET Connection from SSIS Package to get data from table
                string con = Dts.Connections["oledb_conn"].ConnectionString.ToString();
                OleDbConnection _connection = new OleDbConnection(con);
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();

                //Read distinct error euerries 
                query = "select distinct ErrorQuery, SheetName from ErrorMapping where FileType = 'PremiumFile'";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
                cmd.CommandText = query;
                cmd.Connection = _connection;
                _connection.Open();
                DataTable dt_ErrorMapping = new DataTable();
                dt_ErrorMapping.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
                _connection.Close();

                if (dt_ErrorMapping != null && dt_ErrorMapping.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (DataRow dt_ErrorMapping_row in dt_ErrorMapping.Rows)
                    {
                        query = dt_ErrorMapping_row["ErrorQuery"].ToString();
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        cmd.CommandText = query;
                        cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
                        cmd.Connection = _connection;
                        _connection.Open();
                        DataTable dt_ErrorInfo = new DataTable();
                        dt_ErrorInfo.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
                        _connection.Close();

                        if (dt_ErrorInfo != null && dt_ErrorInfo.Rows.Count > 0)
                        {
                            Error(dt_ErrorMapping_row["SheetName"].ToString());
                        }

                    }
                }

                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(Dts.Variables["$Package::TempFolderPath"].Value.ToString() + "\\" +
                    "Error" + datetime + ".log"))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine("Error Message: " + exception.Message.ToString());
                    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
                }
            }
        }

        public void ExportExcelFile(DataSet ds, string connstring, string SheetName)
        {
            OleDbConnection Excel_OLE_Con = new OleDbConnection();
            OleDbCommand Excel_OLE_Cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            //Get Header Columns
            string TableColumns = "";
            // Get the Column List from Data Table so can create Excel Sheet with Header
            foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
            {
                foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
                {
                    TableColumns += column + "],[";
                }
            }

            // Replace most right comma from Columnlist
            TableColumns = ("[" + TableColumns.Replace(",", " Text,").TrimEnd(','));
            TableColumns = TableColumns.Remove(TableColumns.Length - 2);

            //Use OLE DB Connection and Create Excel Sheet
            Excel_OLE_Con.ConnectionString = connstring;
            Excel_OLE_Cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
            Excel_OLE_Con.Open();
            Excel_OLE_Cmd.Connection = Excel_OLE_Con;
            Excel_OLE_Cmd.CommandText = "Create table [" + SheetName + "] (" + TableColumns + ")";
            Excel_OLE_Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Excel_OLE_Con.Close();

            //Write Data to Excel Sheet from DataTable dynamically
            foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
            {
                bool firstRow = true;
                String sqlCommandInsert = "";
                String sqlCommandValue = "";
                foreach (DataColumn dataColumn in table.Columns)
                {
                    sqlCommandValue += dataColumn + "],[";
                }

                sqlCommandValue = "[" + sqlCommandValue.TrimEnd(',');
                sqlCommandValue = sqlCommandValue.Remove(sqlCommandValue.Length - 2);
                sqlCommandInsert = "INSERT into [" + SheetName + "] (" + sqlCommandValue + ") VALUES(";

                int columnCount = table.Columns.Count;
                Excel_OLE_Con.Open();
                Excel_OLE_Cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
                foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
                {
                    string columnvalues = "";
                    for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
                    {
                        int index = table.Rows.IndexOf(row);
                        columnvalues += "'" + table.Rows[index].ItemArray[i].ToString() + "',";
                    }

                    columnvalues = columnvalues.TrimEnd(',');
                    var command = sqlCommandInsert + columnvalues + ")";

                    Excel_OLE_Cmd.CommandText = command;
                    Excel_OLE_Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                Excel_OLE_Con.Close();


            }
        }

        public void Error(string ActualSheetName)
        {
            //USE ADO.NET Connection from SSIS Package to get data from table            
            string con = Dts.Connections["oledb_conn"].ConnectionString.ToString();
            OleDbConnection _connection = new OleDbConnection(con);
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            //drop Excel file if exists

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ActualSheetName))
            {
                //FileType='PremiumFile'"

                query = "Select ErrorQuery,SheetName,FileType from pol.ErrorMapping Where SheetName = '" + ActualSheetName + "' and FileType='PremiumFile'";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = query;
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
                cmd.Connection = _connection;
                _connection.Open();
                DataTable dt_ErrorInfo = new DataTable();
                dt_ErrorInfo.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
                //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                _connection.Close();

                if (dt_ErrorInfo != null && dt_ErrorInfo.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (DataRow dt_ErrorInfo_row in dt_ErrorInfo.Rows)
                    {

                        query = dt_ErrorInfo_row["ErrorQuery"].ToString();
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        cmd.CommandText = query;
                        //cmd.CommandTimeout = 600;
                        cmd.Connection = _connection;
                        cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
                        _connection.Open();
                        DataTable dt_Actual_data = new DataTable();
                        dt_Actual_data.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
                        //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        _connection.Close();

                        FileName = PackageName + dt_ErrorInfo_row["FileType"].ToString();
                        //TableName = "ErrorFileInfo ";

                        //Construct ConnectionString for Excel
                        connstring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + "Data Source=" + FolderPath + FileName + ";" + "Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;\"";

                        string SheetName = "";
                        object[] array = dt_ErrorInfo_row.ItemArray;
                        SheetName = array[1].ToString();

                        //Load Data into DataTable from SQL ServerTable
                        //string queryString = "SELECT * from " + TableName + " ";
                        //OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, _connection);
                        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                        ds.Tables.Add(dt_Actual_data);
                        //adapter.Fill(ds);
                        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                        {
                            ExportExcelFile(ds, connstring, SheetName);
                            flag++;
                        }
                    }
                }


            }
        }




        #region ScriptResults declaration
        /// <summary>
        /// This enum provides a convenient shorthand within the scope of this class for setting the
        /// result of the script.
        /// 
        /// This code was generated automatically.
        /// </summary>
        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
        #endregion
    }
}
```